# grub-mkconfig doesn't detect /boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 596.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0    25G  0 part /mnt/arch
├─sda2   8:2    0     2M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   4.5G  0 part /mnt/arch/boot
├─sda4   8:4    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda5   8:5    0     4G  0 part /mnt/gentoo/boot
├─sda6   8:6    0 129.5G  0 part /mnt/arch/home
├─sda7   8:7    0 296.3G  0 part /
└─sda8   8:8    0 132.9G  0 part /mnt/gentoo    

sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.18.0-rc7
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.18.0-rc7
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.11.10
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.11.10
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
  No volume groups found
Found Arch on /dev/sda1
Found Gentoo Base System release 2.2 on /dev/sda8
done
sudo os-prober
  No volume groups found
/dev/sda1::Arch:linux
/dev/sda8:Gentoo Base System release 2.2:Gentoo:linux
```

As you can see in the lsblk, I have separate boot partitions in arch and gentoo on /dev/sda 3 and 5 respectively. but, even when all partitions are mounted, grub and os-prober do not detect /boot partitions for either, leaving both systems unbootable for obvious reasons. I am on a Linux mint setup so I have access to the debian and ubuntu repos. I use GPT partition layout, i;m okay losing my gentoo, I don't want to reinstall arch, and I have one usb lying around to boot from, and one sdcard that can be used for file storage that MUST NOT be overwritten. I tried using bootrepair in a livecd, but when I did, it made mint bootable, but crippled gentoo and arch. Both can be accessed by chroot, and I was able to connect to the box this morning by SSH. I havn't been able to connect by SSH recently, but that isn't my problem. BTW, no problems compiling from source, just let me know where to get the code, and dependencies so I don't have to waste more time. Ive done several kernel compiles, both with and without cheating, so no problems there if I need to.

I know that I'm missing something trivial, that, in hindsight, will seem obvious.

```
EDIT:
```

paste2.org/0MOHzMKN

Also, I have successfully booted into arch linux. I used a live cd to chroot in and `pacman -R grub ; pacman -Sy grub ; grub-install (args)`
Problem now? Gentoo and linux mint don't show up on the list.

Edit 2: using the 1-2 punch of os-prober and grub-mkconfig from INSIDE arch, I have restored funtionality to Linux mint, and added gentoo onto the list. i now how a full grub menu, that boots into arch and mint, but not gentoo.

EDIT 3:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chroot

```
pacman -R grub
pacman -Sy grub
grub-install
os-prober
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

iI used the help of the bootrepair scripts from yannubuntu. It did all of the configuration necessary to recognize the /boot partition from arch, but not gentoo.
The problem is technically solved. I have reached a comfortable state.
However, the question is not fully answered. To all those reading this, This will be accepted as an answer 72 hours after now. If anyone wants 15 free stack rep."
"

Comment: http://paste2.org/0MOHzMKN

Comment: Forgot that I don't care about gentoo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste2.org/0MOHzMKN

Also, I have successfully booted into arch linux. I used a live cd to chroot in and pacman -R grub ; pacman -Sy grub ; grub-install (args) Problem now? Gentoo and linux mint don't show up on the list.

Edit 2: using the 1-2 punch of os-prober and grub-mkconfig from INSIDE arch, I have restored funtionality to Linux mint, and added gentoo onto the list. i now how a full grub menu, that boots into arch and mint, but not gentoo.

EDIT 3: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chroot

pacman -R grub
pacman -Sy grub
grub-install
os-prober
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

iI used the help of the bootrepair scripts from yannubuntu. It did all of the configuration necessary to recognize the /boot partition from arch, but not gentoo. The problem is technically solved. I have reached a comfortable state.